# Why does 'tail -c 10K' cause it to read an entire 16GB flash drive?

Tags: tail, block-device

To view the last 10K of a 128GB internal SSD I used:

```
sudo tail -c 10K /dev/sda | xxd
```

This worked as expected and immediately output the data.

However when I try to view the last 10K of a 16GB USB flash drive:

```
sudo tail -c 10K /dev/sdb | xxd
```

The entire device is read first, which takes about 10 minutes, then the data is output.

Why is there a difference? And is there a way I can prevent this from happening (without having to resort to using `skip=` and `seek=` in `dd`)?

Comment: How do you check the amount of reading each `tail` is doing? Can you share the result for each one?

Comment: may by SDD drive is read fully, and you don't notice ?

Comment: Can you run `sudo strace -c tail -c 10K /dev/sda >/dev/null` and see how many `read` calls are done?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Conky shows constant disk reading at ~30MiB/s for about 10 minutes.

Comment: @Archemar: I doubt it. The SSD is unformatted.